# Выполнить запрос myslqi с пользовательской переменной?

Tags: php, mysql

Мне нужно выполнить такой код:

```
SET @id = 0;
;
SELECT 
    @id := @id+1,
    table.`field1`,
    table`field2`
FROM `table`
```

Но он не выполняется ни в query ни multi_query. Как мне все-таки его выполнить? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перепишите запрос в таком виде:

```
SELECT  @id := @id+1, table.`field1`,  table`field2`
  FROM `table`,(select @id:=0) A;
```

Т.е. переменную обнуляем прямо в запросе, а не перед ним, отдельным предложением.

Comment: Да, теперь работает в один запрос, спасибо! А как быть если нужно вообще какие-нибудь переменные объявлять или скрипт в запросе составлять?

Comment: Любые переменные можно объявить практически в любом запросе. Если в запросе нет `from`, например в update, то можно написать в `where 0=(select @id:=0)`.  Со скриптами сложнее, боюсь их надо в виде хранимых процедур оформлять. Вообще в интернете много примеров с multi_query и судя по ним несколько предложений через точку с запятой работать должны. Так что надо конкретные случаи рассматривать, почему то или иное может не работать.

Comment: Может он у вас вторую точку с запятой не понял после set. у вас одна с set в строке и еще одна отдельно.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за объяснения!

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы в РНР выполнить два запроса к БД, надо два раза обратиться к соответствующей фуркции API:

```
$mysqli->query("SET @id = 0");
$mysqli->query("SELECT @id := @id+1, field1, field2 FROM table");
```

Comment: А так разве сработает? Я думал метод возвращает результат к единственному запросу.

Comment: Не понял. Какой метод к какому запросу? В любом случае, это единственно правильный вариант.

Comment: Ну query это метод объекта $mysqli. НУ вот человек выше отписал рабочий вариант в один запрос. Сейчас проверю этот.

Comment: Использовать надо не "рабочий" вариант, а правильный.

Comment: Вы тролите? Чем предыдущий вариант неправильный? Да и этот работать не будет, потому что каждый query должен возвращать результат. То есть будут идти два разных запроса.

Comment: я извиняюсь, проверил - все работает, видимо я опечатался где-то когда первый раз проверял. Спасибо большое за ответ и еще раз извините.